# Stopwatch elapsed output

Tags: c#

I had some code that crunched a lot of data, so I started it on Thursday and left it running over the weekend. On Monday, I have come back and seen that it finished. I used a stopwatch function to track the length of time the code ran for. However, I ended up with

```
Elapsed: 2.18:57:55.xxx
```

I understand that it's output is normally H:M:SS, but don't understand the first digit, especially since it's been running for days. Did it just convert from hours to days? Did I leave it running so long that it broke?

EDIT: Sorry, I didn't mean that it finished on Monday. I just meant that BY Monday (when I returned to the computer), it was done.

Comment: did your machine perhaps suspend / hibernate when it had nothing more to do?

Comment: Did you call ToString() on the output?

Comment: also: is there any chance you actually started it on Friday, not Thursday?

Comment: No, it isn't. According to my logs, it started at on Thursday, 11:00 AM and finished around Sunday 6:00 AM.

Comment: Thursday 11 AM to sunday 6 AM is 2 days and 19 hours. So the output seems to be correct. 2 days 18 hours 57 minutes 55 seconds xxx milliseconds

Comment: The documentation for the type (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ecy8h51.aspx) of the `Elapsed` property seems pretty thorough...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes - that's the format of [`TimeSpan.ToString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ecy8h51.aspx):

> The returned string is formatted with the "c" format specifier and has the following format:
>
> [-][d.]hh:mm:ss[.fffffff]
>
> Elements in square brackets ([ and ]) may not be included in the returned string. Colons and periods (: and.) are literal characters. The non-literal elements are listed in the following table. Note that the string returned by the ToString() method is not culture-sensitive.

Since there's not a format specifier that shows total hours, you'll need to calculate it.  If you want the hours to be shown as a single number then use:

```
TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(2,18,57,55);
    
var output = string.Format("{0}:{1}",
                           ts.Days*24 + ts.Hours,
                           ts.ToString("mm\\:ss\\.ffff"));

//output =  `66:57:55.0000`
```

Comment: If started Thursday and checked on Monday, there is all-of a Friday, Saturday and Sunday in the middle; we would expect a `3.something`, no?

Comment: Its easier to use `ts.TotalHours`

Comment: @SysDragon except TotalHours includes the fractional part and would round up if you formatted it without decimals - you could truncate the number but would that really be easier?

Comment: @MarcGravell Sounds like the OP _checked_ on Monday but the stopwatch _stopped_ on Sunday.

Answer (score 0):

That's expected behaviour. From the docs for [Timespan.ToString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/1ecy8h51.aspx):

> The returned string is formatted with the "c" format specifier and has the following format:
>
> [-][d.]hh:mm:ss[.fffffff]
>
> "d" - The number of days in the time interval. This element is omitted if the time interval is less than one day.

Comment: If started Thursday and checked on Monday, there is all-of a Friday, Saturday and Sunday in the middle; we would expect a `3.something`, no?

Comment: @MarcGravell The question was unclear, but from the updates it's clear that the question is regarding the output format, not the output value :)